# Variable is undefined, after giving it to a function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that transforms hex to string. 
Console then says: "hex is undefined on line 148", which is:
"hex = hex.toString()". Any reason why this is happening?

```
function hexToStr(hex) {
    hex = hex.toString();
    var str = '';
    for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: How do you call `hexToStr()`?

Comment: That error message will occur if you pass an undefined value into the function in the first place (or call the function with no parameter, like `hexToStr()`.  Make sure that whatever's calling this function is passing the value you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to work fine. Maybe add a check to make sure the input is a string, just to be safe.

```js
function hexToStr(hex) {
  if (typeof(hex) !== 'string') throw ('Input a string')
  var str = '';
  for (var n = 0; n < hex.length; n += 2) {
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(n, 2), 16));
  }
  return str;
}

function handleClick() {
  var input = document.getElementById('hexGoesHere').value
  var output = hexToStr(input)
  document.getElementById('stringGoesHere').innerText = output
}
```

```html
<input id="hexGoesHere" type="text" value="48656c6c6f20776f726c6421"></input>
<button onClick=handleClick()>Convert</button>
<p>Output:</p>
<p id="stringGoesHere"></p>
```